# MutationObserver not working

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

Consider the following code:

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.target.nodeName);
  });
});

observer.observe(document, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
});
```

```html
<div>
  <ol contenteditable oninput="">
    <li>Press enter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

which is a slight modification of [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/).

Interacting with the [jsbin version](http://jsbin.com/hivivaboxa/1/edit?html,js,console,output) page does not produce any log. Where am I wrong? Notice that if I substitute line

```
  observer.observe(document, {
```

with

```
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('ol'), {
```

the script turns on working...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It doesn't appear to work because you are not mutating anything that you are observing. You are neither changing

- attributes (`attributes: true`) of the `document` node (which is understandable, since `document` doesn't have attributes)
- child nodes (`childList: true`): the only child node of `document` is the `<html>` node, and you are not removing or replacing it.
- character data (`characterData: true`): you are not changing any Text, Comment, or ProcessingInstruction children of `document` (also understandable because `document` cannot have such children).

If you replace the `<html>` node, you can see that the mutation observer works just as configured.

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.target.nodeName);
  });
});

observer.observe(document, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
});

document.replaceChild(document.createElement('div'), document.documentElement);
```

---

What you are doing is changing the content of the `ol` element, which is a **descendant** of `document`.

If you want to listen to these kind of changes, you have to set `subtree` to true:

```
observer.observe(document, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  characterData: true
});
```

More information in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.target.nodeName);
  });
});

observer.observe(document, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  characterData: true
});
```

```html
<div>
  <ol contenteditable oninput="">
    <li>Press enter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `characterData: true` description isn't quite right. `characterData` applies when observing a text/comment/processing-instruction directly or via `subtree: true`, not when those node types are children of the observed element.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Wasn't sure how `subtree` impacts the other settings. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone using Chrome thats tried the above solutions, try restarting Chrome.

```
function callback() {
   console.log("mutation occured")
};
console.log("about to run")
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(document, { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true});
```

For me the most basic example, logging every possible change with document as the target still wouldn't fire the callback until I restarted Chrome.

Comment: It worked for me, but sometimes it doesn't work and I need to restart Google Chrome again. Is there a bug filed for this?

Comment: Restart chrome work for me. Stuck for 1 hour for this figuring out why callback not working

Comment: I was able to solve this by simply closing the tab and re-opening it. CTRL+W and CTRL+SHIFT+T was all I needed to do thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76011518/11224924).

Answer (score 1):

Closing the current tab and reopening the url in new tab also does the trick.
For my case I had set a breakpoint which had caused chrome to disturb the observer

Comment: I had the exact same issue and managed to resolve it the exact same way thanks to this answer. I added a breakpoint in my mutation observer, iterated through a couple of times, and as soon as I reloaded the page I noticed that the MutationObserver completely stopped observing mutations.

Comment: Based on the fact there's been two recent answers and two recent comments (plus myself) on an inactive, 8-year-old post, there's likely a new chrome bug - someone should report it.